# Apps Scripts - Copy Column E To Column K of Another Sheet but add constant values into other columns (Column B and D)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I wrote the following script to copy over the constant values of column E of Sheet 1 to column K of the sheet 2 which is good so far. But, I want to add two values which are Name and Color to column B and D right next to each row that has been copied over to the sheet 2, respectively. I am unsure how to write for loop for this. At the moment it only copies the constant values to the first copied row.
Dummy sheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FGiGGiEoaYjq0KicC10PXx3AiwdvpCap9k4KUvQdQ-g/edit?usp=sharing

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=="sheet 1" && e.range.columnStart==1 && e.value=="TRUE") {
    const tsh=e.source.getSheetByName('Sheet 2');
    const nr=tsh.getLastRow()+1;
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,2,1,1).copyTo(tsh.getRange(nr,2,1,1));
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,4,1,1).copyTo(tsh.getRange(nr,4,1,1));
    sh.getRange('E3:E').copyTo(tsh.getRange(nr,11,1,1));

 
  }
}
```

Comment: So what's keeping you from making the change?

Comment: This is probably not correct `sh.getRange('E3:E').copyTo(tsh.getRange(nr,11,1,1));` because the implication is that there is more than just one row in 'E3:E' and there is only one row in the target.

Comment: these `sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,2,1,1).copyTo(tsh.getRange(nr,2,1,1));` should be written like this: `sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,2).copyTo(tsh.getRange(nr,2));`

Comment: it would really help to show us two screenshots. One of the input and one of the output. It does not have to be real data, just some mock data that demonstrate exactly your situation.

Comment: Sure, I will add it now. One moment please. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: dummy sheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FGiGGiEoaYjq0KicC10PXx3AiwdvpCap9k4KUvQdQ-g/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

I put some often used code into variables. Since you want to paste in a non-contiguous range, I split `setValues` to three different lines. Of course there are better ways to do that, for example, use list of ranges or put empty columns in between but I decided to keep it simple.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const rng = e.range;
  const row = rng.getRow();
  const col = rng.getColumn();
  const sh = rng.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=="Sheet 1" && col == 1 && e.value=="TRUE") {
    const tsh=e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet 2");
    const nr=tsh.getLastRow()+1;
    const size = sh.getRange("E2:E").getValues().filter(String);
    const len = size.length;
    const product = new Array(len).fill([sh.getRange(row,2).getValue()]);
    const color = new Array(len).fill([sh.getRange(row,4).getValue()]);
    tsh.getRange(nr,2,product.length,1).setValues(product);
    tsh.getRange(nr,4,color.length,1).setValues(color);
    tsh.getRange(nr,11,size.length,1).setValues(size);
  }
}
```

Be careful with the sheet names. In the mock data you shared, you have `Sheet 1` and `Sheet 2` but in your code you have  `sheet 1` and `Sheet 2`. Make sure the names matches exactly, namely no additional spaces and no different upper or lower case letters. There has to be an exact match.