# Merge the following regular function and onEdit function to obtain the desired result

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to merge these two functions below to get the desired output which is the following:

Lets assume, we have size variations available in Column E of Sheet 1. So, I want the function to copy each record in sheet 1 to sheet 2. But, each copied records gets copied multiple times depending on the number of size variations available (Col E); plus, one copy which will not contain the size variation just the product info. Basically, first copy of the record will just contain info such as product, color, purchase date. Following copies of this record will contain the size variations but not the purchase date.

For reference dummy sheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_-978mgxiRrN5LcLFALtfrhMm_ULSy_jhS2kbYrGLNk/edit?usp=sharing

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet 1');
  const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet 2');
  const sizes = sh1.getRange('E2:E5').getValues().flat();
  const vals1 = sh1.getRange('A2:D'+sh1.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const values = vals1.filter(r=>r[0]==true).map(([,b,c,d])=>[b,c,d]);
  const emptyAr = [...new Array(3)].map(elem => new Array(3));
  const valuesAr = values.flatMap(r=>[r,...emptyAr]);
  const sizesAr = new Array(values.length).fill(sizes).flat().map(c=>[c]);
  const lrow = sh2.getLastRow();
  sh2.getRange(lrow+1,2,valuesAr.length,valuesAr[0].length).setValues(valuesAr);
  sh2.getRange(lrow+1,11,sizesAr.length,sizesAr[0].length).setValues(sizesAr);
  
}




function onEdit(e) {
  const rng = e.range;
  const row = rng.getRow();
  const col = rng.getColumn();
  const sh = rng.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=="Sheet 1" && col == 1 && e.value=="TRUE") {
    const tsh=e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet 2");
    const nr=tsh.getLastRow()+1;
    const size = sh.getRange("E2:E").getValues().filter(String);
    const len = size.length;
    const product = new Array(len).fill([sh.getRange(row,2).getValue()]);
    const color = new Array(len).fill([sh.getRange(row,4).getValue()]);
    tsh.getRange(nr,2,product.length,1).setValues(product);
    tsh.getRange(nr,4,color.length,1).setValues(color);
    tsh.getRange(nr,11,size.length,1).setValues(size);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

You want to copy the product and color based on the number of the size elements.

**Replace:**

```
const valuesAr = values.flatMap(r=>[r,...emptyAr]);
```

**with:**

```
const valuesAr = values.flatMap(r=>[...new Array(sizes.length)].map(elem => r));
```

and you can now delete `emptyAr` and you can also get rid of the `onEdit` trigger if you don't need it.

### Solution:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet 1');
  const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet 2');
  const sizes = sh1.getRange('E2:E5').getValues().flat();
  const vals1 = sh1.getRange('A2:D'+sh1.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const values = vals1.filter(r=>r[0]==true).map(([,b,c,d])=>[b,c,d]);
  const valuesAr = values.flatMap(r=>[...new Array(sizes.length)].map(elem => r));
  const sizesAr = new Array(values.length).fill(sizes).flat().map(c=>[c]);
  const lrow = sh2.getLastRow();
  sh2.getRange(lrow+1,2,valuesAr.length,valuesAr[0].length).setValues(valuesAr);
  sh2.getRange(lrow+1,11,sizesAr.length,sizesAr[0].length).setValues(sizesAr);
}
```